# Gnome doesn't work in tty7

Tags: linux, xorg, gnome, startx

I am using Debian. Everything were fine, but after I have my first reboot, I got a black screen after boot in tty7. I switched to tty1 and did startx and it worked(I have graphics in tyy1 ), but still I have a black screen in tty7.
How can I solve that?
Btw, I am sorry that I didn't attached logs, I actually don't which logs are relevant, and how to get them, so I will attach what you need

The output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` is:

```
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

The output of `systemctl status gdm3` is:

```
gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-01-22 21:20:45 GMT; 13h ago
  Process: 2032 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2028 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/gdm3" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2037 (gdm3)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
           ├─2037 /usr/sbin/gdm3
           └─2043 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -novtswitch -background none -noreset -ver...
```

Comment: Please specify the debian version or better the output of the command `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @gollum No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release: 8.2
Codename: jessie

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` ? Probably it will show `/usr/sbin/lightdm`. If that is the case then show the output of the command `systemctl status lightdm`. Note: you might want to edit your question and update your question with that information.

Comment: @gollum Actually, the output is: /usr/sbin/gdm3. The output of systemctl status gdm3 is in the question above

Comment: Ok. If you reboot, wait for the black screen, switch to tty1, login as user root and enter `systemctl restart gdm.service` .. what happens?

Comment: @gollum it switches to tty7, and I see a black screen as before..

Comment: And on tty7 if you press any keys or move your mouse the black screen stays? Have yo also installed all updates? `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Also post the output of `journalctl -u gdm.service` somewhere (e.g. on pastebin) and give the link.

Comment: @gollum Yes, the screen stays black. Also, I have installed all updates. Here is the output of journalctl -u gdm.service: http://pastebin.com/uTUAAbpZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34753/discussion-between-gollum-and-gtalst12).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gollum, after some retries, we have figured out that the problem is with gdm, so the solution was to install lightdm (apt-get install lightdm), and it fixed the problem.